# Can we hide/obscure symbol names in the symbol table of ELF executable object file?

Tags: unix, elf, object-files, symbol-table

According to [this](http://sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/contents.html) ELF specification: ELF object file contains various [sections](http://sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.sheader.html) and one of them is [symbol table section](http://sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.symtab.html) `.symtab` which contains information of all symbols (files, functions, objects etc).

ELF contains information like name, attribute flags, type, value and binding etc for each symbol in the symbol table.

The name of an object for a file, function or object (array, variable, string) etc. actually exposes the internal information of the code. This way any person can analyze an ELF (using `strings`, `objdump` or `readelf` tools) and see this information and get idea of things internal to the code which should be kept secret.

For readability and maintainability we write code which can be understood by the developers. So, we need to keep using proper file names and variable names etc. We cannot obscure them using [code obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025494/obfuscating-c-c-code) as it will make it difficult to maintain.

**Question (edited):** Is there any way by which we can hide or remove symbol "names" from the symbol table of executable ELF so that no one can get the insight of code and the executable is still operational?

Comment: What do you mean by obscure symbol tables? once the elf file is a fully executable with fully resolved symbols, the symbol table ( not the dynamic one though ) is useless, I'm not sure what you mean by "obfuscation" - making it immune against RE and code analysis and keeping the code fully executable?

Comment: @DrPrItay Yes, hiding or removing "names" (text strings) of these symbols and making it still executable. Is it possible to strip off the names of the symbols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way by which we can hide or obscure symbol names in the symbol table of ELF so that no one can get the insight of how code is developed (without code obfuscation)?

Depends on what *kind* of ELF file you are shipping to the end user.

If you are shipping a fully-linked ELF executable, running `strip a.out` will remove symbol table completely (but *not* the dynamic symbol, which *must* remain for obvious reasons).

If you are shipping an ELF shared library, you need to carefully control its exposed API using `-fvisibility=hidden` or a linker version script. If you do, `strip` will again remove everything except your public API.

If you are shipping a relocatable ELF object (or an archive library), then you *can't* do anything about its symbol table (again for obvious reason: symbol table is used to perform the final link).

Finally, your question appears to be predicated on *misconception*:

> We cannot obscure them using code obfuscation as it will make it difficult to maintain.

The usual way to apply code obfuscation is *just* before you make the final shipping product (i.e. at exactly the same point where you would use `strip`, or any other method that would hide implementation details). Applying code obfuscation *at that point* will make the result difficult to maintain in *exactly* the same way as any other method of hiding implementation details.

Notably, you *don't* (usually) apply obfuscation to the code under development and maintenance (i.e. your development builds remain un-obfuscated).

Comment: 'strip' command works on executable ELF, as you suggest. Thank you for the detailed answer and insightful information.

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood, what do you mean by "strip works"? After a `strip`, `nm` doesn't display symbols, *but* `readelf` still has a lot of information.

Comment: @Demi-Lune If you ask a separate question about `strip` vs `readelf`, I can answer it. Chances are, you are exporting the symbol in question via dynamic symbol table, and `nm -D` will *also* display this symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `strip` to remove static library symbols and you can remove dynamic library symbols by loading the library yourself instead of letting the OS do this automatically.